# Packet filtering with the u32 selector does not work

Tags: linux, iptables, qos, traffic-filtering, traffic-shaping

I'm trying to figure out whether the QoS solution I integrated into my RaspberryPI works or not.

I found out that port-based traffic classification doesn't work, so I tried to check the filters used in the mentioned QoS solution on my Ubuntu machine.

Here is my dummy setup: *(eno1 is an Ethernet interface connected to Raspberry)*

```
# Root qdisc is prio with 3 bands
sudo tc qdisc add dev eno1 root handle 1: prio bands 3
# Band 1 - port 2323 with low rate, high packet loss probability and big delay
sudo tc qdisc add dev eno1 parent 1:1 netem rate 8kbit delay 500ms loss 0.3% 25%
sudo tc filter add dev eno1 parent 1:0 protocol ip u32 match ip dport 2323 0xffff classid 1:1
sudo tc filter add dev eno1 parent 1:0 protocol ip u32 match ip sport 2323 0xffff classid 1:1
# Band 2 qdisc is tbf and filter is outbound SMTP
sudo tc qdisc add dev eno1 parent 1:2 tbf rate 1mbit buffer 100000 latency 100s
sudo tc filter add dev eno1 parent 1:0 protocol ip u32 match ip dport 25 0xffff classid 1:2
sudo tc filter add dev eno1 parent 1:0 protocol ip u32 match ip sport 25 0xffff classid 1:2
# Band 3 qdisc is sfq and filter is anything unfiltered
sudo tc qdisc add dev eno1 parent 1:3 sfq perturb 16
sudo tc filter add dev eno1 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 9 u32 match u8 0 0 classid 1:3
```

I limited the rate and added a massive delay for all traffic that runs in and from port 2323.
**Unfortunately, all the packets go through the band 3:**

```
hping3 192.168.2.10 -p 25 -c 5
HPING 192.168.2.10 (eno1 192.168.2.10): NO FLAGS are set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes
len=46 ip=192.168.2.10 ttl=64 DF id=0 sport=25 flags=RA seq=0 win=0 rtt=3.8 ms
len=46 ip=192.168.2.10 ttl=64 DF id=0 sport=25 flags=RA seq=1 win=0 rtt=3.7 ms
len=46 ip=192.168.2.10 ttl=64 DF id=0 sport=25 flags=RA seq=2 win=0 rtt=3.5 ms
len=46 ip=192.168.2.10 ttl=64 DF id=0 sport=25 flags=RA seq=3 win=0 rtt=3.2 ms
len=46 ip=192.168.2.10 ttl=64 DF id=0 sport=25 flags=RA seq=4 win=0 rtt=3.1 ms

--- 192.168.2.10 hping statistic ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 3.1/3.5/3.8 ms

tc -s -d qdisc show dev eno1       
qdisc prio 1: root refcnt 2 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 Sent 2612 bytes 26 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc tbf 800d: parent 1:2 rate 1Mbit burst 100000b/1 mpu 0b lat 100.0s linklayer ethernet 
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc netem 800c: parent 1:1 limit 1000 delay 500.0ms loss 0.3% 25% rate 8Kbit
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc sfq 800e: parent 1:3 limit 127p quantum 1514b depth 127 flows 128/1024 divisor 1024 perturb 16sec 
 Sent 2612 bytes 26 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
```

**But if I add the following rule to iptables, packets are correctly classified:**

```
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -o eno1 -p tcp --dport 2323 -j CLASSIFY --set-class 1:1
```

I don't want to add more tc/hping output here, because it will make my question too long, but I see the 500ms delay in the hping statistics, and the packets I send to port 2323 are displayed in the tc statistics.

Could someone please advise where to search for a problem? Why u32 selector does not work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note for below: in `tc filter ...` syntax, `pref` and `prio` are synonyms, so I'll use `pref`/preference rather than `prio`/priority to avoid any confusion with the unrelated `prio` in the classful `prio` qdisc used in `tc qdisc ...`.

The first two groups of `tc filter` rules for 1:2 and 1:3 above don't specify any preference, so each inherit a default preference: starting from 49152 and decreasing: newer rules take precedence over previous rules by default. The last command with preference 9 will always be evaluated first.

Here are the filter rules displayed back. They are displayed by order of preference:

```
# tc -s filter show dev eno1
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 9 u32 chain 0 
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 9 u32 chain 0 fh 804: ht divisor 1 
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 9 u32 chain 0 fh 804::800 order 2048 key ht 804 bkt 0 flowid 1:3 not_in_hw  (rule hit 5 success 5)
  match 00000000/00000000 at 0 (success 5 ) 
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 49149 u32 chain 0 
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 49149 u32 chain 0 fh 803: ht divisor 1 
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 49149 u32 chain 0 fh 803::800 order 2048 key ht 803 bkt 0 flowid 1:2 not_in_hw  (rule hit 0 success 0)
  match 00190000/ffff0000 at 20 (success 0 ) 
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 49150 u32 chain 0 
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 49150 u32 chain 0 fh 802: ht divisor 1 
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 49150 u32 chain 0 fh 802::800 order 2048 key ht 802 bkt 0 flowid 1:2 not_in_hw  (rule hit 0 success 0)
  match 00000019/0000ffff at 20 (success 0 ) 
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 49151 u32 chain 0 
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 49151 u32 chain 0 fh 801: ht divisor 1 
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 49151 u32 chain 0 fh 801::800 order 2048 key ht 801 bkt 0 flowid 1:1 not_in_hw  (rule hit 0 success 0)
  match 09130000/ffff0000 at 20 (success 0 ) 
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 49152 u32 chain 0 
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 49152 u32 chain 0 fh 800: ht divisor 1 
filter parent 1: protocol ip pref 49152 u32 chain 0 fh 800::800 order 2048 key ht 800 bkt 0 flowid 1:1 not_in_hw  (rule hit 0 success 0)
  match 00000913/0000ffff at 20 (success 0 )
```

So always specify a preference for each and every filter rule, with low values for rules having to match first and use the highest value for a rule that plays the role of a default rule. Unless these preferences are for very similar filters (eg sport/dport to same classid), each value should be different.